# How to limit gvim man page hot key settings on c/c++?

Tags: vim

I found the gvim 8.0 can not press 'K' hotkey to show man page properly in my environment.
The gvim is launched on linux side. And I use 'ssh -X' to redirect the gvim screen to my local windows VcXorg screen.

I found when I press 'K' on one word of main.c(for example memset), it will show ugly ANSI code on screen.

I trying to hack the ~/.vimrc as following

```
if has("gui_running")
  nnoremap K :<C-U>! man v:count "<C-R><C-W>" \| col -b \| gview -c 'set ft=man nomod nolist' -<CR>
endif
```

When I press 'K' on ~/.vimrc, it will cause wrong behavior.
So, I'm wonder is it possible to limited this hotkey only workable on c/c++ file?

Answer (score 1):

So, this command gives you a basic non-styled `man` experience compatible with GVim's "dumb" terminal emulator:

```
$ man foobar | col -b
```

You can use it in Vim with a little bit of Vimscript:

```
" executes the command above with the right argument at the right place
function! DumbKeywordPrg(argument) abort
    execute "!man " . a:argument . " | col -b"
endfunction

" :DumbKeywordPrg foobar calls DumbKeywordPrg('foobar')
command! -nargs=1 DumbKeywordPrg :call DumbKeywordPrg(<q-args>)

" tell Vim to use :DumbKeywordPrg as 'keywordprg'
" this works like doing :DumbkeywordPrg foobar with the cursor on foobar
set keywordprg=:DumbKeywordPrg
```

Now, to enable that feature for C/C++ only, you have the choice between two methods:

- with an autocommand in your `vimrc`:

  ```
  augroup cfamily
      autocmd!
      autocmd FileType c,cpp setlocal keywordprg=:DumbKeywordPrg
  augroup END
  ```
- with a proper ftplugin:

  in `after/ftplugin/c.vim` (which will be sourced for C *and* C++):

  ```
  setlocal keywordprg=:DumbKeywordPrg
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to limit this hotkey only workable on c/c++ file?

Yes you can do it by modifying the if statement to:

```
if has("gui_running") && (&ft=="c" || &ft=="cpp")
```

Comment: Can't not work, It will cause the 'K' mapping back to `:! man 'memset'`, I guess maybe it can not just set in ~/.vimrc directly